# Get second part of a string using RegEx

Tags: regex

I have string like this "first#second", and I wonder how to get "second" part without "#" symbol as result of RegEx, not as match capture using brackets

upd: I forgot to add one more special char at the end of string, real string is "first#second*"

Comment: Which language? Must you use regex?

Comment: Regex might be overkill for this simple example, if your String will always consist of `first#second` and not nested `#`, you can use the built-in String functionality (for whatever language you need this for) to locate the `#` and take the substring of that position+1.

Comment: You might find a more efficient solution for a string pattern *that* simple by using whatever language support exists for substrings.

Comment: Unfortunately, I forgot one more special char at the end of string, it should be "first#second*"

Comment: I've found solution for my need (using lookahead)

[\w]*(?=\*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple regex:

```
/#(.*)$/
```

If you really don't want it to be a match capture, and you know there's a # in the string but none in the part you want, you can do

```
/[^#]*$/
```

and the whole regex is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you must use regex, and you insist on not using capturing groups, you can use lookbehind in flavors that support them like this:

```
(?<=#).*
```

Or you can also capture just anything but `#`, to the end of the string, so something like this:

```
[^#]*$
```

The capturing group option, of course, is:

```
#(.*)
 \__/
   1
```

This matches the `#` too, but group 1 captures the part that you want.

Lastly, a non-regex alternative may look something like this:

```
secondPart = wholeString.substring( wholeString.indexOf("#") + 1 )
```

There may be issues with some of these solutions if `#` can also appear (perhaps escaped) anywhere else in the string.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), [Brackets for Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: This is the most complete answer, and the look-behind approach (the first one mentioned here) is the one I would use.

Answer (score 2):

```
/[a-z]+#([a-z]+)/
```

Comment: OP apparently does not want to use capture groups (although "not as match capture" may be open to interpretation).

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookaround to exclude parts of an expression.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

if your using java then

you can consider using Pattern & Matcher class. Pattern gives you a compiled, optimizer version of Regular expression. Matcher gives a complete internals of RE Matches.

Both Pattern.match & String.spilt gives same result where in first is compartively faster.

for e.g)

```
String s = "first#second#third";
String re = "#";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
Matcher m = p.matcher();
int ms = 0;
int me = 0;
while( m.find() ) {
    System.out.println("start "+m.start()+" end "+ m.end()+" group "+m.group());
    me = m.start();
    System.out.println(s.substring(ms,me));
    ms = m.end();
}
```

if other language u can consider using back-reference & groups also. if you find any repetitions.