# Matching Second part of MIME Content Type using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I've seen a number of examples on StackOverflow to get the "second" part of a MIME content type. What I'd like is, when provided with: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

I'd like to return just: html

The Regex I've seen thus far has been something like:

```
/[^text/]*$/
```

But in my testing, the matched result is just "ml"

I want whatever lies after the "text/" in the string, but for whatever reason all I'm getting is the last two letters.  To be clear I consulted a number of other posts including:

[Get second part of a string using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388520/get-second-part-of-a-string-using-regex)

Which I thought would be exactly what I want, but my tests show that regex does not work.Any help would be much appreciated.

edit to broaden up the question.  I'm trying to isolate part of the Content-Type returned in the jquery object.

```
    var regex_content = /[^text/]([^;\s]+)/
    var contentType = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
    alert(contentType.match(regex_content));
```

With the regex_content that someone else provided, html,tml is returned if the content type is text/html; charset=ISO-SOMENUMBERS.  I'd like to ONLY have html be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be:

```
^text/([^;\s]+)
```

and capture the first group.

And since threre is a / in your regex, use the `new RegExp()` constructor:

```
var re = new RegExp("^text/([^;\\s]+)");
```

Comment: This returns: html,tml. Is there some minor change we could make to just get: html?

Comment: You only put the regex, not the code you actually use. Update your question ;) Or don't be bothered and use Guava (recommended!).

Comment: Updated. Unfortunately Guava is not an option.

Comment: Ah, so you are using JavaScript and not Java... THis makes a difference! See updated answer.

Comment: Well, isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: I wanted to isolate "html" not get "text/html,html"

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your regex is that it ignores the characters `t`, `e`, `x`, and `/` individually and matches other characters. You want to match the group that follows the `/` and precedes the `;`, so your regex would be

```
/(?:[^/]*\/)([^;]*)/
```

This has a non-capturing group (`(?:[^/]*/)`) match (and ignore) the characters up to the first `/`, then a capturing group (`([^;]*)`) to match and keep the text you want before the first `;`.